# include class file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to cakephp. I have to include one third party class file 'class.googleHelper.php' in my controller. This file is placed in app/vendors/ directory. 
From the cakephp tutorial I used -

```
App::import('Vendor', 'class.googleHelper');
```

but it not works.
Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you place directly in your vendors directory?
it is better to create a subfolder like "Google" and

```
App::import('Vendor', 'googleHelper', array('file'=>array('Google/class.googleHelper.php')));
```

PS: this looks like a cake written helper - why treating it as a vendor then?